# Returned location is null in TomTom Android SDK

Tags: java, android, tomtom, tomtom-android-sdk

I'm trying to use TomTom's SDK for my Android app so I was practicing this tutorial https://developer.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-android/android-tutorials-use-cases/search-along-route but whenever I'm trying to invoke `tomtomMap.centerOnMyLocation()` I get an error. It used to work but now my returned location is always null.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register map ready callback

```
mapFragment = (MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
mapFragment.getAsyncMap(onMapReadyCallback);
```

then enable location:

```
private OnMapReadyCallback onMapReadyCallback =
        new OnMapReadyCallback() {
   @Override
   public void onMapReady(TomtomMap map) {
      //Map is ready here
      tomtomMap = map;
      tomtomMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   }
};
```

Forward permissions callbacks from `Activity` to `TomtomMap` to support runtime permission:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    tomtomMap.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```