# TomtomMap.getUserLocation() returns always null?

Tags: android, tomtom, tomtom-android-sdk

I trying to get the devices location, but the TomtomMap.getUsersLocation() is always returning null.

The wired thing is that since i set TomtomMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true) the map marks the user location correctly, but when i try to get it for my self it returns null.

I followed the documentation on how to do it, it was very simple to follow, it just does not work.
I also checked the answer below, but it is just a copy of the docs.

[Returned location is null in TomTom Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276653/returned-location-is-null-in-tomtom-android-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to guess without looking at the code, but most probably you are trying to get user location too early when GPS position is not yet available (perhaps inside `onMapReady` callback).

To make sure that you are getting the user location as quick as possible you can override the `onLocationChanged` callback.

Please find an example activity code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationUpdateListener, OnMapReadyCallback {

private TomtomMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Register onMapReady callback
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
    mapFragment.getAsyncMap(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(@NonNull TomtomMap tomtomMap) {
    this.map = tomtomMap;

    // Enable location and register location listener callback
    this.map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    this.map.addLocationUpdateListener(this);
}

// Forward permissions callbacks
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    this.map.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // Use map.getUserLocation() without getting NULL
    Toast.makeText(this, this.map.getUserLocation().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Remove location listener if needed
    this.map.removeLocationUpdateListener(this);
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped me find the real problem.
I found out that i was calling tomtomMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); for a second time just before calling tomtomMap.getUserLocation(); this must have caused the user location to be calculated once again and requested without giving it time to finish. Thank you very much. :)